# Calling a function at the end of every cmdloop iteration (cmd module)

Tags: python, cmd

I am using the `cmd` module to build a little command line app and I am trying to call a function at the end of every cmd loop.

The only way I found to do this is to override `cmdloop` and add my function call in it. 
Isn't there a much simpler/cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement [the `postcmd` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmd.html):

> **Cmd.postcmd(stop, line)**
>
> Hook method executed just after a command dispatch is finished. This method is a stub in Cmd; it exists to be overridden by subclasses. line is the command line which was executed, and stop is a flag which indicates whether execution will be terminated after the call to postcmd(); this will be the return value of the onecmd() method. The return value of this method will be used as the new value for the internal flag which corresponds to stop; returning false will cause interpretation to continue.

The method will be called on your object (inheriting from `cmd.Cmd`) after each cmd has been performed. As long as you return `False` from this method  execution will continue.